# Ethers.JS: convert an HDNodeWallet to a SignerWithAddress from Hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I'm testing my dApp...
I wish to use randomly generated wallets to perform operations on my contracts, including transfers (`sendTransaction({})`)
The 20 `SignerWithAddress` coming with HardHat are not sufficient. I want more.

So I tried `ethers.Wallet.createRandom()` which creates a `HDNodeWallet` type object.
Unfortunately.this type cannot perform unchecked transactions:
`Error: missing provider (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.11.0)`

Now either I adapt my transactions to be "checked" or I need a way to convert a `HDNodeWallet` to a `SignerWithAddress` type.

This is the transfer function:

```
await holderSigner.sendTransaction({
    to: randomGeneratedUsers[i].address,
    value: ethers.parseUnits('10', 'ether'),
});
```

These are the missing methods:

```
Argument of type 'HDNodeWallet' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HardhatEthersSigner'.
Type 'HDNodeWallet' is missing the following properties from type 'HardhatEthersSigner':
toJSON, _sendUncheckedTransactionts (2345)
```

Ideas?